# add Analytics tool in the ios application

Tags: ios, objective-c, google-analytics, analytics, flurry

I want to add Analytics tool in my iPhone application. I have found [Google Analytics](http://www.google.com/analytics/), [Asking Point](http://www.askingpoint.com/) and [Flurry](http://www.flurry.com/).

Now which is the best analytics tool form them and why ? or is there any other tool available ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I use flurry, they have a great platform and very easy to integrate. Flurry also seems more focused on mobile.  Most people use flurry, but I think some are starting to switch to google analytics, although i have' t personally used them, however their focus isn't just mobile, but they are great at dealing with web pages.

Flurry can let you track any event. A downside would be the reporting time, sometimes it can be hours, and as far as downloads it seems to update everyday.

I would use both for a few weeks and see which one you like better. It will probably come down to your preference.